# How to load specific values to a ViewHolder item of a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view with a custom listadapter. Inside the getView method of my adapter I intialize the layout of my rows. Inside each row there is a TextView.

I would like to pass specific values to the TextViews of specific rows. Is it possible?

The adapter code is here:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;

        final Model model = arrList.get(position);

        if (row == null) {

            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            holder.button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
            holder.numberPicker = (com.lol.helen.widgets.NumberPicker) row.findViewById(R.id.numb_pickr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to pass custom data through holder. But be careful what you're holding for holder since a holder is tied to its view only and since views are recycled you'll end up using same holder for more views. If you need to keep some state info for a specific view position, store that data in model object.